# Why would I need to update from Facebook PHP SDK 4 to 5?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK to verify users.

They have to log into Facebook and accept my app to access certain parts of my website. I use no other functionality beyond checking if visitors are logged into Facebook and retrieving their Facebook ID.

I set this up using Facebook PHP SDK version 4. It still runs. Updating to SDK version 5 would be a bit of a hassle, so I'd like to avoid it.

Is there a reason that I need to update to version 5? Will version 4 stop working soon? Are there security risks that have been addressed with the new version? Anything else I forget?

My website is a normal website (mobile first), not a special iOS or Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to upgrade, both SDKs use the same API in the background. As long as the API does not change, the SDKs will work even for years.
Make sure you understand the difference between "Graph API" (current version 2.6) and "PHP SDK". Check out the changelog once in a while: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 1):

According to the Facebook [Platform Versioning](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions) page:

General (APIs & SDKs):

> Each version is guaranteed to operate for at least two years. **A version will no longer be usable two years after the date that the subsequent version is released.**

SDKs:

> For SDKs, a version will always remain available as it is a downloadable package, however beyond it's end-of-life date, it may rely upon APIs or methods which no longer work, so you should assume an end-of-life SDK is no longer functional.

From what I can tell, Facebook SDK v5.0 was released in July 2015.  That implies that that v4.0 has 1 year to go before there is some risk that it may become "no longer functional".

There is also the issue that if the SDK is beyond end-of-life then it won't receive any further updates; i.e. no bug fixes, no security patches, no porting to newer versions of PHP, etc.

Comment: that´s about api version, NOT sdk version. you can even still use v3.x of the php sdk.

Comment: @luschn - I have added the relevant text about SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5) for comparsion between v4 and v5 & new features.

It's always good to stay updated. And sooner or later you have to do it. If it's hassle to do it now you can do it later I guess. Even If there were security risks in v4 they won't publish until removal of v4.